# preg_match массивая [1]

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день.

Есть строка

```
$str = "stroka[1]";
```

Как с помощью preg_match убедиться, что в ней есть данные по шаблона [0-9] ?

Comment: `if (preg_match('~\[\d+]~', $s)) { echo "Есть!"; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Как с помощью preg_match убедиться, что в ней есть данные по шаблона [0-9] ?*

Передать символьный класс [0-9] первым параметром:

```
$str = 'stroka[1]';

$patt = '~[0-9]~';
preg_match($patt, $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```